# Prevent access controller methods directly from URL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

For some reasons, I do not want to access from url like `examples.com/controller/method`. I want to force Codeigniter to use `routes.php` instead. I do not want to use `private`, `protect` or `_method`.
Please, help! I am using Codeigniter 3

Comment: Suggest you tell us why you want to do this - will be easier to help find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

In codeigniter, the methods you write in controllers are to be accessed in the url that is its mvc structure. 
If you want to avoid a function in the controller to be seen in the url, simply make that function private/protected or prepend an _ in the function name.

```
private func_name
```

or

```
public _func_name
```

or

```
protected func_name
```

any of the options in your functions won't allow access to your functions in the url. 
If you want you controller function to be accessed by other subclasses, you ll need to make the function public or protected as required and to avoid it to be accessed by the url simply prepend an underscore _

Comment: Thank you for ur answer but I said that "I do not want to use private, protected or _method. " because my goal is force to use routes.php, private, protected or _method not allow us to route via routes.php.  Are there any solutions?

Comment: @duyvu1311 have you found solution for that. i am also searching. right now my problem is that i have not manson controller on route still i can access by just url.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution in Codeigniter 4, just go to routes and set autoroute to false

```
 $routes->setAutoRoute(false);
```